# How to move HANA view definitions from testing enviroment into prodution enviroment

Tags: hana

I have created the attribute views and analytical views in our testing environment using HANA Studio, then I need to create these same views in our production environment.

I would ask whether there is a simple way to do this(I just dont' want to repeat the creation).

eg, export the view definition from testing enviroment and then import it into production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [document "Setting up the transport" in SAP Library](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a4d43a319ecf464e9d838454a6bdb9ad/2.0.04/en-US/50a00deb7663496d93ebb938bbb723ca.html)?

You definitely do not recreate the objects manually. You can either use delivery units

Comment: Please add a context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there ([FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)) More details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) how to better answer.